# Copying columns from 2D array into object 1D array

Tags: java, object, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to copy the columns of a 2D array into a 1D array. The Stock class I created has a double[] array named data. The last loop tries to print some values that should be in the first Stock object, but it actually prints the values from the last object.

```
Stock arr[] = new Stock[numcols];   // creates array with the same n of slots as columns
        double[] temp = new double[numrows-1];

        for(int i=1; i<numcols; i++){
            for(int j=1; j<numrows; j++){
                temp[j-1] = fluct[j][i];
            }
            arr[i-1] = new Stock(temp, compName[i-1], price[i-1]);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<numrows/20; i++)
            System.out.println(arr[0].data[i] + arr[0].name);
```

In fact, if I loop printing arr[j].data[i] it will print the same values for all j. It seems the loop is creating all objects with the same values for each Stock, but I see no reason why it is doing so.

I've checked the 2D array fluct and all values there are in order. I start the loops at position 1 as the values in position 0 are of no interest. Also tried printing separately the values of temp[] and they were correct, but still the data in the objects was wrong.

Here's the Stock object (omitted the getMean/getDev methods for brevity):

```
public class Stock{
    public static double[] data;
    public static String name;
    public static double stDev;
    public static double price;
    public static double mean;

    public Stock(double[] newData, String newName, double newPrice){
        this.data = newData;
        this.name = newName;
        this.price = newPrice;
        this.mean = getMean();
        this.stDev = getDev();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with were you define your **temp** array. You should do it inside the first `for` loop:

```
Stock arr[] = new Stock[numcols];   // creates array with the same n of slots as columns

for(int i=1; i<numcols; i++){
    double[] temp = new double[numrows-1];
    for(int j=1; j<numrows; j++){
        temp[j-1] = fluct[j][i];
    }
    arr[i-1] = new Stock(temp, compName[i-1], price[i-1]);
}
for(int i=0; i<numrows-1; i++)
    System.out.println(arr[0].data[i] + arr[0].name);
```

This way for every **arr** element a new temp will be used. Currently you are using the same **temp** object and it's values are being updated as well as the values for **arr** elements.
Also I've changed to condition for the last for loop to `i<numrows-i`. Don't know why you needed `i<numrows/20` =)

Good luck with Java studying!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried declaring temp inside the loop but still got the same output. Also tried initialising the Stock objects before doing these loops but didn't work either. 
On that last loop, I was dividing by 20 so it would only print a few values, otherwise i'd be waiting for all values to be printed, and there's loads! Thank you again

Comment: Well that's strange.... Have you tried declaring `temp` inside the loop and `Stock` outside of it at the same time? If yes, than the output should be the same, only the issue would be with the `Stock` variable... Both the `temp` and the `Stock` type variables should be defined inside the loop.
Do you mind to copy-paste my snippet into your code and see it it's working properly or not?

Comment: Tried copying an pasting your code and it didn't work either, still get the same output. I've added my code for the Stock object, I suspect that's where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrassing, but I finally figured out what was wrong. In my object class I had my variables static! Removing that solved it.